# how to convey different message with proper status code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-services, asp.net-web-api

I used the below code in my c# web service project which is a MVC WebAPI. When client calls my service I have three possibilities  . One is there is response to return, second one is there is no response to return because "No configuration found" and third one is also no response because "Same configuration is found".

Now my question is can I use the same HttpStatusCode.NoContent for third scenario also by just changing the message ? So the client who receives the response needs to differentiate by message which I feel is not a good solution. I feel I should pick some other status code , but the meaning may not be appropriate.

```
 response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NoContent;
 response.ReasonPhrase = "No Configuration Found.";
```

Can anyone suggest me what is the best approach in this scenario ?

Comment: are you using web API or web services?

Comment: Yes, It's a MVC WebAPI project

Comment: you can use status codes according to your sense, like conflict,notfound,nocontent etc,but remember one thing this are all used by the MVC to handle http request and response.

Comment: for example you can return a status code notfound when you found no elements. MVC framework will throw the same error if you call some api method that doesn't exists.so that time it will very difficult to differentiate the both.

Comment: @frebin, yes that's what my worry is when method doesn't exist the same response may come. I am looking at options if any exist.

Comment: you can use meaningful api response codes if you are providing the api for third party purpose. otherwise you can decide what to do.

Answer (score 0):

These status codes are HTTP status codes and and are set by W3 with HTTP protocol standarts. This means you can not override and/or change them. They are fixed through all web.

But you are free to throw any of the erronous codes (mostly are 4xx or 5xx format) amd handle them properly on the client-side. As long as you do it properly user will not notify anything wrong.